# Multiple instances of an aurora mysql db. Only one of them does not use the possible index

Tags: mysql, database, amazon-aurora, database-indexes

I ran into a performance issue with a large query, and broke it down with explain.
Dev and production are fine but the QA DB is having trouble.

Here is a sanitized explain

```
EXPLAIN SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM  table1 t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.correlation_id = t1.correlation_id
WHERE t2.request_id = '<varchar(100) here>';
```

In one developer instance of the db I get

```
select_type, table, partitions, type, possible_keys, key, key_len, ref, rows, filtered, extra
SIMPLE,t2,,ref,request_id,request_id,1022,const,3753,100,Using where
SIMPLE,t1,,eq_ref,"correlationIdUniqueConstraint,idx_correlation_id",correlationIdUniqueConstraint,402,dev_db.t2.correlation_id,1,100,Using index
```

Production is very similar / identical.
So everything seems fine so far.

However in the QA db I'm getting

```
select_type, table, partitions, type, possible_keys, key, key_len, ref, rows, filtered, extra
SIMPLE,t2,,ref,request_id,request_id,1022,const,1176,100, <null>
SIMPLE,t1,,ALL,"correlationIdUniqueConstraint,idx_correlation_id",,,,3271577,10,Range checked for each record (index map: 0x40000004)
```

Using the schema compare tool in datagrip I made the Developer & QA dbs match.
The only difference would be the exact rows/counts. However in terms of rows Production > QA > Dev and yet Production & Dev are fine.

Schema info if relevant:

```
request_id has an index
correlation_id is varchar(100) in both t1 & t2.
The correlation_id unique constraint & index exist on t1
```

I confirmed with

```
SELECT CHAR_LENGTH(correlation_id)
FROM merchant_analysis
WHERE CHAR_LENGTH(correlation_id) > 90;
```

That no correlation_ids even exceed 90 chars much less 100.

Some DB info:
5.7.mysql_aurora.2.07.2
QA & Production Ram > Dev RAM

I'm hoping someone has seen a gotcha like this before, and I don't have to recreate the QA db.

Comment: Is `'<varchar(100) here>'` a string?  Or a column name?

Comment: It's a string, technically a uuid.

Comment: Are they standard 26-character UUIDs?

Comment: It's 8-4-4-4-12

Answer (score 0):

This composite (and covering) INDEX would make the query more efficient on all machines:

```
table2:  INDEX(request_id, correlation_id)
```

And drop the current `INDEX(request_id)` since it would be in the way of picking this better index.

PS; it is not a `LEFT` join, but a normal `INNER JOIN`.  (This because of the demand `WHERE t2... = ...`)

As for why it might use a different query plan -- is the data different?  The Optimizer dynamically picks the plan based on probes into the data.  Even if the data is identical, the 'random' probes could come to different conclusions.

Comment: The data is different. It should follow the same pattern though.
Yeah the left join got generated by an ORM and I just left that part as-is for the manual / not ORM tests.
Hmm. What kind of data diff do you think would cause it to not pick the index?

Comment: `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON` and Optimizer Trace may provide clues.